# Substrate - interacting with node issue

Tags: substrate

I am creating my first substrate chain (online tutorial).

Installed node.js and yarn - and attempting to start node in development mode `<./target/debug/node-template --dev --tmp>`,

when I run code keep getting error -

```
no such file or directory...
```

Obviously, I am doing something wrong, and would like to know how to solve this issue?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you did not compile the node.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible scenarios as to why you encountered the said issue:

1. Since ./target/debug/node-template is a relative path, you have to be on the ditectory where the target folder is located in
2. Build your node-template using cargo build

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

I have built and compiled the Node Template [substrate-node-template] using [cargo build] ...

I checked the folder [substrate-front-end-template] to ensure that [yarn] and [node.js] are installed:

- versions installed - yarn 1.22.5 / node 12.18.4

In [substrate-front-end-template] directory I run following code:
./target/debug/node-template --dev --tmp

Receive error 'is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet function......' –

Is the target folder located where I have installed yarn and node.js?

Comment: Solved - I found that I can open multiple console windows from the dropdown 'default shell' - The 1st window ‘cd substrate-node-template/ ‘and run  ‘cargo build –release’. In addition, opened a 2nd window ‘cd substrate-front-end template’ and run ‘start yarn’. I can connect to web page [http://localhost:8000/] and view information about the chain.